# WCF MaxArrayLength Changing Setting Won't Stay

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding, wcf-wshttpbinding

I am trying to upload files using WCF.  Everything under 16K works fine, but anything over throws this error:

There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Byte[]. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader

This is my WCF Service app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IRAISAPI" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="50000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="104857600"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="RAIS_WCF_Services.RAISAPI">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="RAIS_WCF_Services.IRAISAPI">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/RAIS_WCF_Services/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

and here is my client app.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IRAISAPI" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="50000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="104857600"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/RAIS_WCF_Services/Service1/"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IRAISAPI"
        contract="RAIS.IRAISAPI" name="WSHttpBinding_IRAISAPI">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any help is much appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like your service is not properly referring to your binding configuration.

Search in your service config for WSHttpBinding_IRAISAPI and you'll see what I mean.

You need:

```
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              contract="RAIS_WCF_Services.IRAISAPI"  
              bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IRAISAPI">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
```

Comment: that was it...stupid oversight.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It's REALLY easy to miss those when you're doing stuff by hand!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean the maxArrayLength setting isn't being set automatically in your client configuration after adding a service reference and/or it is getting lost after updating your client's service reference?  If this is what you're experiencing, this is by design.  Settings such as timeouts, maxArrayLength, etc are not exposed in WSDL and therefore cannot be pushed to the client by the service when the service reference is created/updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this [global config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816881.aspx) to your server-side configuration. This will tie your service binding to a binding configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <remove scheme="http"/>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IRAISAPI" />
    </protocolMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
```

You can also use `behaviors/serviceBehaviors/behavior/serviceMetadata/httpGetBindingConfiguration` for a more localized solution.